# Expose docker port to external wan interface in a linux host with iptables rules

Tags: linux, iptables, docker

I have a host with two nic one lets call eth0 and another eth1.

eth0 is local lan and has no iptables filters.
eth1 is a wan and has iptables dropping everything.

Also I've a docker with a service in the port 80.

When I run the docker I map the port 8086 to the 80.
Then I open the firewall with:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1  -p tcp  -m tcp --dport 8086 -j ACCEPT
```

The result is:
I can reach the service from the internal lan in the expected port 8086 and no response from WAN.

I've tested the traffic in the wan nic with:

```
tcpdump -i any -n port 8086
```

I missing something, how can I open that port?

The result of

```
iptables -L
```

is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8086
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:466
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1521
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:12540
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:https

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

How can I expose that port to the public wan?

Answer (score 0):

No answers, so I'm going to commnet my walkaround, it is not desired answer, but it's ok.

I finally  setup a nginx working as reverse proxy listening to all interfaces. That was valid for me because it is http traffic.